# How to input command line arguments to a dotnet c# program using bash scripts?

Tags: c#, .net, bash, shell

I have a simple c# program that expects command line input (from **Console.ReadLine()**) when ran. There's a lot of inputs I have to provide, so I was wondering how I could automate this process. I currently have a shell script that attempts to do this, but it's not working.

```
#!/bin/sh
dotnet run #run the program
1          #input first argument (this failed so I tried echo 1 instead but no luck)
           # <- rest of command line inputs on each line
```

Not really familiar with shell scripts, and I'm not fixed on this solution if you had another solution in mind. My OS is MacOS.

Comment: _"--    Delimits arguments to dotnet run from arguments for the application being run. All arguments after this delimiter are passed to the application run.
"_ - [dotnet run - Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run#options)

Comment: ^^ So, that would mean to pass parameter "1" => `dotnet run -- 1`

Comment: Not so sure about the newlines, though. Haven't tried if that works.

Comment: Just tried it, the newlines won't work

Comment: I just managed to have numbers on a new line with continuation "\" but only without comments and string arguments didn't work neither. (I am using dash for POSIX compliant scripts)

Comment: @Fildor I should clarify that my program takes arguments with Console.ReadLine()

Comment: Yeah, that would have been great to read in the question.

Comment: @Fildor sorry!! Super new to this, LearningAlongTheWay ahaha. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: I removed the tag commandline-arguments, since that would be confusing. People would expect what I expected - actual cmd-line-args. :D

Comment: Do you have any capacity in changing the program, so it would accept for example a json file or a csv or xml as input instead of asking via Console.ReadLine?

Comment: What you can do is pipe a file to the app ... I'll try and write up an answer.

Comment: @Fildor there are too many Console.ReadLines() to go in and change unfortunately. So the solution has to be something that doesn't require changing the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so what I tried was this:

1. I made a little mcve-Console App: (dotnet 6)

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
while( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) )
{
    Console.WriteLine("User input: {0}", input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

2. Then I made a little `input.txt`

```
This is a Text.
This is another Text.
1
2
3
This is the final Text.
```

3. and finally `run.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
dotnet run < "input.txt"
```

Output was

```
User input: This is a Text.
User input: This is another Text.
User input: 1
User input: 2
User input: 3
User input: This is the final Text.
```

/bin/sh is linked to dash shell in my case.

---

If in `run.sh` you replace "input.txt" with "$1", then you can call it with `./run.sh whateveryourinputfileis.txt` to make a little more flexible.